# ExpressJS replaces req.parameter with filename from folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have issue with ExpressJS route and what is returns on get request.

My code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');
const port = 80;

app.get('/results/:timestamp', function (req, res) {
  var filepath = path.join(__dirname + '/../testresults/' + req.params.timestamp + '/report.html');
  res.sendFile(filepath);
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '!'));
```

And this is how folder with content looks like 
[folder with files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dfBA.png)

The problem is following:
When I enter url:
 *http://localhost/results/2017-12-20-16.3*
expressJS is trying to return file of path:
*'[...]\testresults\app.js\report.html'*

if I change in code 'report.html' to any other file in that folder, it sends correct file from existing path. But when I try to return any "xyz.html" file it tries to send file from "testresults/app.js/zyx.html" instead of "testresults/2017-12-20-16.3/xyz.html".

So when I try to send any .html file it replaces my timestamp parameter with "app.js". But when I try to send any other extension it sends it normally. This is weird.

I have honestly no idea why this code behaves this way. I don't understand it at all. This code worked well few weeks ago. Now it's like this.
Any idea how to solve this weird issue?

Comment: So you're trying to serve a file from the folder *testresults* one directory up from `app.js`?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging, such as adding `console.log` statements to see what the values of different variables (`req.params.timestamp`, `filepath`, etc.) are at different points in the program?

Comment: @gh0st app.js is in the same folder as report.html.  I included the screenshot

Comment: @EricB I used console.log to check values and result is that given timestamp and also filepath are correct (timestamp is folder name, filepath is correct path to report.html) However res.sendfile() tries to send file of different path - instead timestamp it uses 'app.js'. This is sick!

Comment: So Before res.send() filepath is "[...]\testresults\2017-12-20-16.3\report.html" but  the res.send() itself is trying to send from path [...]\testresults\app.js\report.html'"

Comment: @EricB Ok I just discovered another thing. When I use console.log(req.params.timestamp) it is executed twice before res.send() is executed. At first run it displays an actual timestamp given in parameter. At second run it displays "app.js". Wtf?